# get the value of a listview subitem

Tags: c#

I have a code in C#. I have a listview then what I want is to get the value of the subitem specifically the Subtotal subitem which contains the subtotal price of the orders. I want to sum up the values and display to result to a textbox in the same form. How can I do that? Here's my code:

```
AddOrderForm add = new AddOrderForm();
        foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
        {
            add.nametb.Text = drow["Menu"].ToString();
            add.Pricetb.Text = drow["MenuPrice"].ToString();
            add.listBox1.Items.Add(drow["MenuDesc"].ToString());
            add.orderqtytb.Focus();
            add.ShowDialog();                
        }
        if (add.isAddOrder)
        {

            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.Text = add.nametb.Text;
            item.SubItems.Add(add.orderqtytb.Text);
            item.SubItems.Add(add.Pricetb.Text);              

            double total = 0;
            try
            {
                total = double.Parse(add.Pricetb.Text) * double.Parse(add.orderqtytb.Text);
            }
            catch
            {
                total = 0;
            }
            item.SubItems.Add(total.ToString("0.00"));
            Listview.Items.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can retrieve an `Item` value or its `SubItems` in a `ListView` this way:

suppose your ListView is like this:

```
public void AddDataToLvw(){
            ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("item1", 0);
            item1.SubItems.Add("1");
            item1.SubItems.Add("3");

            ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("item2", 1);
            item2.SubItems.Add("4");
            item2.SubItems.Add("6");

            ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("item3", 0);
            item3.SubItems.Add("7");
            item3.SubItems.Add("9");

            // Create columns for the items and subitems.
            listView1.Columns.Add("Item Column", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Column 2", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Column 3", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

            listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item1, item2, item3 });

}
```

then you can access its subitems like this:

```
 private void GetSubItems()
    {
        int total = 0;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            total += Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems[1].Text);

        }
        MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());
    }
```

notice the index that I've passed in `item.SubItems`. you should pass that subitem index, which you want to sumup

Answer (score 2):

Your code already adds the items to the Listview correctly, Assuming you want to retrieve the value of column 'total' on say SelectedIndexChanged event, you can do -

```
ListView.Items[SelectedItemIndex].SubItem[2].Text
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to construct a class like this

```
class MyClass
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
    public string PropertyC { get; set; }
    public string PropertyD { get; set; }
}
```

While building the Listview you generate this class fill the properties and add the object of the class to the Tag of the ListViewItem

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.PropertyA = "A";
myClass.PropertyB = "B";
myClass.PropertyC = "C";
myClass.PropertyD = "D";

ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.Text = myClass.PropertyA;
item.SubItems.Add(myClass.PropertyB);
item.SubItems.Add(myClass.PropertyC);
item.Tag = myClass;
```

Now you can take the object from the Tag and you have your values

```
MyClass myClassForLaterUse = (MyClass)item.Tag;
MessageBox.Show(myClassForLaterUse.PropertyA);
```