# Summarize all numbers of a column in Listview

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, visual-studio, listview

Edit: I found the solution myself. Its

```
textBoxNettobetrag.Text = Convert.ToString(19,90 * i);
```

Please close the thread. Thx!

I would like to easily sum up all numbers in the second column of my listView1. No whole numbers, but currency. Screenshot: [listView1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyHY5.png)

Can't quite figure out how to do get the values out now. Can anyone help me out? New into programming and learning everyday. **Thank you very much!**

```
string[] arr = new string[2];
        arr[0] = "Sicherheitshelm";
        arr[1] = "19,90";

        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(arr);
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);

for(int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++) { 
         listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].ToString();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get the value of a listview subitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541901/get-the-value-of-a-listview-subitem)

Comment: Hey, thanks. Not quite, It does make me even more confused to be honest. I'm one step away to get the value out, but how hmm :/

Comment: @Ozan Answer yourself by using "Post Your Answer", then mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add up all SubItems, so you'll need a loop for this as well. To add up all the values, you have to convert them into a numeric value, int for example, and add them up.

You can use TryParse for this. It returns false, if the string cannot be converted, and true otherwise.

```
        int totalSum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Count; j++)
            {
                int subItemValue = 0;
                if(int.TryParse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[j], out subItemValue))
                {
                    totalSum += subItemValue;
                }
            }                
        }
```